# variable value not changing in a function

Tags: python-3.x

My issue is Im trying to change the value of i within the function primeChecker however the value stays the same at 3, the number i never changes even though I have lines of code that adds to that value.

Code:

```
number = input("How many numbers? ")
i = 3
a = 0
h = 0
modulus = {}
intnumber = int(number)
modulusCounter = 0
exceptionPrime = [2]
prime = [3, 5, 7]
print("lengthprime", len(prime))

def modulus(i, a):
    print("i:", i)
    print("modulus", prime[a])
    modulus = i % (prime[a])
    return primeChecker

def primeChecker(i, a, prime, modulusCounter, h):
    h += 1
    #print("B: ", b)
    for c in range(len(prime)):
        #print("1 check")
        #if modulus(i,a) == 0:
        if modulus(i, a) == 0:
            print("1 check")
            print("i value: ", i)
            modulusCounter += 1
            print("modulusC", modulusCounter)

        else: #elif modulus(a,i) != 0:
            a += 1

    print("modC: ", modulusCounter, "a: ", a, "length: ", len(prime), "i: ", i)

    if a == len(prime) and modulusCounter == 0:
        print("Prime: ", i)
        print("i: ", i)
        prime.append(i)         
        i += 2
        modulusCounter = 0          
        a = 0
        return i
    elif a != len(prime) or modulusCounter != 0:
        print("not prime")
        i += 2
        modulusCounter = 0
        a = 0
        return i

for b in range(intnumber-3):
    primeChecker(i, a, prime, modulusCounter,h)

print(prime)
print(len(prime))
print("h: ", h)
```

I've tried returning b instead of returning i at the end of the functions. I've tried updating i with, newi = i, but I ran into the same issue with that. I don't know why i is not changing, so Im wondering where did my error occur?

Comment: Is all that code really relevant to your question? Please see [mre], and condense your code down to one.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.